# Turtlebot model appears only partially by using Interactive Marker

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume in the sample at [Turtlebot Interactive Marker tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_interactive_markers/Tutorials/UsingTurtlebotInteractiveMarkers), `RViz` requires sensor/joint inputs from actual `Turtlebot` or the mimicked `Turtlebot` on `gazebo` (similar is mentioned [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/1782/how-to-use-urdf-for-robot-visualization-in-rviz) about `gazebo`-`RViz` interaction too). So I launch both Turtlebot on gazebo (using `turtlebot_gazebo` stack) and the model on `RViz` (`turtlebot_interactive_markers` stack), but in my environment, only the base of Turtlebot is shown and `RViz` shows error on `tf` inputs (see snapshot below). Also, clicking "Interactive" on `RViz` doesn't allow the arrows that are shown in the example. Can anybody tell me what I should add on where?

[image]

`launch` file for the robot: http://pastebin.com/gAUmNL81. I also looked at `turtlebot_viz/turtlebot_interactive_markers/src/turtlebot_marker_server.cpp` but haven't figured out change that might fulfill my request.

I did `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot*` and tried both on Ubuntu 11.04 & 10.10. Thanks.

---

PS. What I specifically want to do is to show Turtlebot on RViz, and let it move according to `vel_cmd` or similar message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11746/turtlebot-model-appears-only-partially-by-using-interactive-marker/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked at it and there are some bugs that seemed to have crept into the code. I'll be doing a release in the next day or so you can pull from trunk to get the fixes. I have filed a ticket here: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/87

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1